# Android Studio code style: how to enforce tabs but allow each dev to have their own tab size?

Tags: android-studio, settings, project, indentation

I want to commit my project settings to my repository and I want to enforce tabs instead of spaces. This is easy enough.

But I don't want to enforce a tab size. Some folks may want to code seeing a tab size of 4 and others may want to code seeing a tab size of 2.

Yet I cannot seem to find a way to do so.

Is there any way to override project tab size with personal local tab size?